# Copy email field data to another custom field

Tags: integration

All,

I am loading Contacts from an external system using upsert operation. For the upsert, I have chosen a custom field as ExternalID because I can't choose the standard email field as ExternalID. We already have data in Production org about 70K contacts..I was wondering How can I copy the data from standard field to custom field for the existing data? For the new records that are created via UI, I am planning to create a workflow rule which will copy the email to custom field but I am not sure what do to for the existing data. Would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To build upon Keith's answer so that you can avoid the governor limit issues.

```
for(List<Contact> contacts : [SELECT Id, Email, MyCustomField__c FROM Contact WHERE MyCustomField__c = null AND Email != null])
{
    for(Contact c : contacts)
    {
        c.MyCustomField__c = c.Email;
    }
    update contacts;
}
```

Keep in mind that even though the DML is in the for loop, this is perfectly valid for big data best practices as it utilizes the built in query and queryMore methods. Please see https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm for further information.

Comment: your doesn't work for more than 100 records, because the dml statement is inside the for loop...

Comment: Christian please read the supporting docs. Because of the structure this for loop uses query and queryMore and chunks the calls in batches of 1000. This is practical for larger amounts of data.

Comment: @techbusinessman In general you are right but you had to add a 2nd for loop... https://gist.github.com/cdeckert/ac99ab8afc882ea759be And btw. I think you are hitting the "Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries" limit... (because you try to update more than 70k records).

Comment: Hi Christian, you are correct. I will update my answer with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Download all records (inc. email and Id) and update all existing records
2. Implement a trigger which copies the data from your standard field to a custom field and update all records.
3. Create a batch job which updates all records.

My suggestion is to go for option 1. Download all the data and upsert the data again.

**Pseudo Code for #2**

```
/** Trigger header before insert / update**/

for(Contact c : trigger.new)
{
    c.custom_email__c = c.email;
}
```

After the trigger was implemented you can use the data loader to download all contact ids. And in a 2nd step you can upload (and update) all records..

Comment: Thanks..I guess option#2 may not work here as we are dealing with existing records..I don't think I can make the trigger fire for the existing records without making any changes unless If it used without option#1. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: # 2 works too...

Answer (score 0):

I would run this in the developer console:

```
Contact[] contacts = [
        select Id, Email
        from Contact
        where MyCustomField__c = null
        and Email != null
        limit 5000
        ];
for (Contact c : contacts) {
    c.MyCustomField__c = c.Email;
}
update contacts;
```

multiple times. The query ignores records that have already been updated and so progresses through all the records. Including the limit aims to keep the query and update within governor limits - lower it if you hit governor limits (because of e.g. triggers on Contact if any).