# Copying Lookup formula field to a "Phone" Field workflow rule

Tags: workflow

I have a custom object and have a lookup formula field from contacts (phone) and would like to copy that to insert it to "Phone" field so my RingCentral click to call will work.

Am I doing this right?  I created a work flow and action. 
[image: workflow]

[image: action]

Comment: I basically need to copy a lookup field to a phone field.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to fill the Phone field for all existing records. Is that correct? You cannot do this with a workflow, because a workflow will only fire for changed/created records. If you want to do it with a workflow, you would then have to edit all existing records. How many records are involved?

I think this will require some programming. Please see [Copy email field data to another custom field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49870/copy-email-field-data-to-another-custom-field) for someone who had a similar problem.

Comment: makes sense.  thanks ill try this one and see how it goes from there.